# No logro comprender el flujo de este bucle for y setTimeout

Tags: javascript

Me gustaría comprender el flujo y el por qué del output de este fragmento de código:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 1);
}

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 1);
}
```

Me encuentro leyendo un par de ejercicios que se encuentran en un repositorio de GitHub: [Link del repositorio con las preguntas](https://github.com/lydiahallie/javascript-questions/blob/master/es-ES/README-ES.md) Específicamente es la pregunta número 2. Lo que sucede es que no logro comprender bien lo que hace la función setTimeout, debido a que leí que retrasaba la impresión de la variable i, es decir, cada vez que se está ejecutando el primer bucle for, este está creando nuevamente una var de i, y que al momento de imprimirla por consola siempre imprimirá 3. Es decir que el resultado de todo el fragmento de código que indiqué es **para el primer bucle for:** 3,3,3 y **para el segundo bucle for**: 0,1,2. El segundo bucle for me queda bastante claro, pero ¿Como es que imprime 3 veces 3 el primer bucle? Se los agradezco de ante mano.

Comment: El problema es que usa `var` para declarar la variable en el primer bucle. Las variables declaradas con `let` están disponibles en el `"scope"` ("bloque") que fueron creadas, las variables declaradas como `var` ignoran el scope y están disponibles de manera más general, por eso en la arrow function que utiliza en el setTimeout la variable declarada con `let` tiene un valor diferente en cada ejecución. En cambio la variable declarada con `var` al estar disponible de manera "global" no genera valores únicos, pues la arrow function es capaz de acceder a la variable "original"

Comment: Relacionado: [var, let, const... o nada en Javascript](/q/106042)

Answer (score 0):

## Básicamente rádica en la diferencia entre `var` y `let`:

### var (primer for)

Con var, la variable i se declara una sola vez para todos los ciclos, lo que significa que se comparte entre todas las iteraciones del bucle. Como te podrás dar cuenta, el ciclo for acaba cuando `i==3`, pues la sentencia `i < 3` se cumple cuando en la cuarta iteración el valor de i==2 se le suma i+=1.
Es por eso que cuando se accede a la variable `i` en cada `console.log` se imprime 3 veces lo mismo (último valor de `i`)

### let (segundo for)

Con let, la variable i tiene un ámbito de bloque dentro del bucle for. Entiéndelo cómo que en cada iteración, se crea un nuevo i. Es por eso que en la primera iteración seguirá siendo 0, en las segunda 1 y así sucesivamente.

Si deseas más información sobre cómo funcionan los bloques y las declaraciones de variables puedes buscar en la documentación de MDN Web Docs, dando [click aquí.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#)